# how do you create a database that will save the selected dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can you Create a Database with this? And how would you display it?

```
data.iFilm = ["Comedy", "Horror", "Sci-Fi"];
data.iVideoClip = ["Hip-Hop", "Pop", "Rap"];
data.iSerial = ["Serial 1", "Serial 2", "Serial 3"];
```

So this the HTML

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Film" data-content="iFilm" /> Film</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" id="VideoClip" data-content="iVideoClip" /> VideoClip</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Serial" data-content="iSerial" /> Serial</label><br />
<select></select>
```

And this is the Javascript

```
$(function () {
  var data = {};


 data.iFilm = ["Comedy", "Horror", "Sci-Fi"];


     data.iVideoClip = ["Hip-Hop", "Pop", "Rap"];
      data.iSerial = ["Serial 1", "Serial 2", "Serial 3"];

  $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    $("select").html("");
    $("input:checked").each(function () {
      addItemsFromArray(data[$(this).attr("data-content")]);
    });
  });
  function addItemsFromArray (arr) {
    $.each(arr, function (i, v) {
      $("select").append('<option value="' + v + '">' + v + '</option>');
    });
  }
});
```

For example in the checkbox when I select the film and my options showed up Comedy, Horror, Sci-fi and you choose Horror

How do you do that? how do you create a database from that that will save the selected dropdown Horror, how will it save in the database?
How will you only display the Comedy in the view when you want to see it?
For example you will open the users profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the job (now using ES6 features):

```js
var data={film:["Comedy", "Horror", "Sci-Fi"],
          clip:["Hip-Hop", "Pop", "Rap"], 
        serial:["Serial 1", "Serial 2", "Serial 3"]};

$(function(){
 $('input:checkbox').click(e=>  // assign click event handler
  $('#choices').html(           // (re-)assign options to select
   $('input:checkbox:checked')  // find all checked checkboxes
    .toArray()                  // make Array from jquery object
    .reduce((opts,c)=>opts.concat(data[c.id]),[]) // combine all sub-arrays
    .map(o=>'<option value="'+o+'">'+o+'</option>').join('') // options
  )
 )
$('select').change(ev=>{
 try {
localStorage.setItem(this.id,this.value)}
 catch(err){nolosto()}
 });
$('#showchoice').click(ev=>{
 try{
 console.log(localStorage.getItem('choices'))}
 catch(err){nolosto()}
 });
});
function nolosto(){console.log(`unfortunately, this fiddle is sandboxed,
 therefore localStorage does not work here`);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="film"/> Film</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="clip"/> VideoClip</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="serial"/> Serial</label><br/>
<select id="choices"></select><br/>
<button id="showchoice">show</button>
```

Following OP's comment I have added a `localStorage`-way of saving the selected information. Unfortunately this mechanism does *not* work in a SO fiddle, therefore it cannot be demonstrated here in full.

In a "normal" situation `localStorage` will keep stored user values between sessions until the user decides to delete the local cache of their browser.

Comment: For example in the checkbox when I select the film and my options showed up Comedy, Horror, Sci-fi and you choose Horror

How do you do that? how do you create a database from that that will save the selected dropdown Horror, how will it save in the database? How will you only display the Comedy in the view when you want to see it?
For example you will open the users profile